# Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, google-play-services

I'm going crazy.

I'm trying to change admob using google play services. But i'm stuck on this error.

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
```

i've this:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/adViewPers"/>
```

and this:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
<activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

main activity

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

...
private AdView adViewPers;

...

adViewPers = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adViewPers);
adViewPers.setAdUnitId("xxxxxxx");
adViewPers.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adViewPers.loadAd(adRequest);
```

and in dependencies:

[image]

what i'm doing wrong????

Comment: Putting libraries in the build folder is likely to get you in trouble, since that directory can get wiped during a clean build. Also, you should include Google Play services via a Maven-style dependency instead of by including the jar directly.

Comment: @ScottBarta yes you're right.. i've added google-play-service like a file and not like a library. if you write this comment in an answer I will be happy to accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way to include Google Play Services is via a Library dependency in the Project Structure dialog -- instead of adding the jar file as you have done, click the + button > Library dependency. Google Play Services should be in the list.

Also, if you're adding jar files, it's really best to not put them in the build folder -- that can get erased if you do a clean build. The best place is in a libs directory at your module root.

Comment: one question, i've noticed that i receive this message: "The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included." , but everything works fine..

Comment: in the documentation of google I read that this error can safely be omitted