# ADMOB with google play service

Tags: android, admob

I have spend some times on integrating Admob API into the apps but seems like with the new Admob integrated into google play lib, I just couldn't get the work done!

Looking at the sample code given by Google https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start

I do not even able to start a simple demo referring to the so call tutorial, just why Google can't give a sample app that can be tested. A simple thing is twisted into something very hard to be understand. Not to say I am lazy, but I don't believe there isn't easier way.

I am looking at every way to integrate the google play sdk but often get into error

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line 80: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
```

The code in my app:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        showMessage(e.toString());
    }
}
```

The Activity XML:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-6360391144319101/2719936275" />
```

The AndroidManifest xml:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I added google play services lib by right click project->Android->Library->Add. Then, manually added the google-play-services.jar into libs folder in my project, and added into Java Build Path->Add JARs. Lastly check the jar file in Java Build Path->Order and Export. However, the new admob is still not able to be working. As opposed to this new SDK, old standalone SDK is much more easier to be integrated.

Please help me to solve the issue. Any suggestions or comment is very much appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756721/error-inflating-class-com-google-android-gms-ads-adview-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer from [Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756721/error-inflating-class-com-google-android-gms-ads-adview-android-studio)

The better way to include Google Play Services is via a Library dependency in the Project Structure dialog -- instead of adding the jar file as you have done, click the + button > Library dependency. Google Play Services should be in the list.

Also, if you're adding jar files, it's really best to not put them in the build folder -- that can get erased if you do a clean build. The best place is in a libs directory at your module root.