# Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

Tags: android

I am getting this error at run time when i am trying to add Ads in my application.

Here is the Main Activity Class Code :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Prepare the Interstitial Ad
                interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
                // Insert the Ad Unit ID
                interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-123456789/123456789");

                //Locate the Banner Ad in activity_main.xml
                AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);

                // Request for Ads
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()

                // Add a test device to show Test Ads
                 .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                 .addTestDevice("CC5F2C72DF2B356BBF0DA198")
                        .build();

                // Load ads into Banner Ads
                adView.loadAd(adRequest);

                // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
                interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

                // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
                interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    public void onAdLoaded() {
                        // Call displayInterstitial() function
                        displayInterstitial();
                    }
                });


    public void displayInterstitial() {
            // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
            if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
                interstitial.show();
            }
        }
```

Here is the Activity XML File

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.app.MainActivity" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            android:name="com.example.app.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" >


            </fragment>

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
             </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>  


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I have added in Android Manifest File But still it is giving run time error.

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="4323000" />

<activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

Android Version

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

Run Time Error Details:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756721/error-inflating-class-com-google-android-gms-ads-adview-android-studio)

Comment: I am using Eclipse